# Is it possible to access XCode's Target Version and Build Numbers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, versioning

In XCode, for an IOS application target, you can set Version and Build numbers. Is there a way to access these numbers from within a program's code? I have these numbers duplicated inside my app with some user defaults and I keep thinking there's a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like the following...

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]
```

Comment: And for Build number, replace `CFBundleShortVersionString` with `CFBundleVersion`.